# Algorithms for subgraph isomorphism detection

Tags: algorithm, graph, subgraph

[Subgraph isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) is an NP Complete problem.  The most widely used algorithm is the one proposed by [Ullman](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~vkk06001/GraphIsomorphism/Papers/Ullman_Algorithm.pdf).

Can someone please explain the algorithm to me in layman's language? I read the above paper by him, but couldn't understand much.

What other algorithms exist for this problem?

I am working on an image processing project.

Comment: Post a link to a PDF would ya? I suspect that this is homework.

Comment: @Hamish: What kind of school/college gives solving a NP Complete problem as homework? I might join it :)

Comment: Professors in graduate classes like to weed out and recruit geniuses by giving one or two crazy problems on homework sets.

Comment: @Hamish: Thats news to me. I am still an undergraduate and definitely not a genius :)

Comment: NP-complete doesn't mean a problem cannot be solved; it just means that no *exact* algorithm is known that scales polynomially as the input size grows *large*. It is still often possible to find approximate algorithms, and it is usually possible to solve the problem exactly for quite a range of small input sizes. (For example, the traveling salesperson problem can be solved for up to tens of thousands of nodes.)

Comment: @Jack, you officially become a genius once you make it to grad school ;) That is because you no longer have time to drink but to release your true potential.

Comment: I believe so far the most recent progress in the field is [Turboiso: towards ultrafast and robust subgraph isomorphism search in large graph databases](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2463676.2465300) from SIGMOD 2013. The authors also have a [survey paper](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol6/p133-han.pdf) on the existing algorithms in VLDB 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VFLib2 is a C++ library for graph isomorphism finding. It also includes an Ullman implementation: http://mivia.unisa.it/datasets/graph-database/vflib/

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://adriann.github.io/Ullman%20subgraph%20isomorphism.html) tries to give an overview of the algorithm. The original presentation is hard to read because it presents the algorithm as you would write it on a '70s computer.